# Android-Studio implement Background

Tags: android-studio

I have just started programming with Android Studio and I don't know how to put a background image on the design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to import a .jpg or .png by dragging it into your drawable folder. Then create an ImageView by dragging from your toolbox onto the design view of your activity. Finally, on the the Background property of your ImageView, click the square to the right of its text area. It will pull up a wizard where you find all your imported drawables.